# rp2040_hal SPI initialisation no read, write, transfer function

Tags: rust, embedded, cortex-m, rp2040

My struct has a member which is a  SPI type from the [docs](https://docs.rs/rp2040-hal/latest/rp2040_hal/spi/index.html).

```rust
pub struct TMC429<D, CS, const DS: u8> 
where
    D: SpiDevice,
    CS: OutputPin,
    CS::Error: core::fmt::Debug

{
    spi: Spi<Enabled, D, DS>,
    chip_select: CS,
    motors: [MotorConfig; 3]
    
}
```

But  I can't use the read/write/transfer functions, because it is not implemented for `Spi<Enabled, SpiDevice, const DS>`.

I know that the trait Full Duplex has to be implemented by the SPI type, but this is done within a [macro in the rp2040_hal](https://docs.rs/rp2040-hal/latest/src/rp2040_hal/spi.rs.html#252) .
How can I make my spi member have the trait FullDuplex in order to use the transfer function?